# How to update a SQL table using RJDBC in R

Tags: r

I already have a SQL table and I want to update the table on a daily basis. I want to overwrite the table everyday. 
If I use dbWriteTable() command it is giving me an error "ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object".
How can I get rid of this error?
Can I use dbSendUpdate() here? If yes,how?

Comment: Add a date, append data by date. Query with a where clause by date. I'm not a big fan of deleting data...

Comment: Otherwise, you probably have to do a "drop table" query to use `dbWriteTable` again.

Comment: provide your code so others can help

Comment: While horrible to put in an example on SO, while I agree with @cory, if you must replace all data each batch, then either delete the table and recreate it, or just `delete from mytable` before uploading. (You will still need to set `DBI::dbWriteTable(..., create=FALSE)`.)

Comment: BTW: still inline with @cory's statement, my recommendation in order of preference: (1) add a `timestamp with time zone` column, and either set it manually or set a default of "today"; (2) first `delete from mytable`, then `dbWriteTable(..., create=FALSE)`; and last and most discouraged (3) `drop table mytable`, `dbWriteTable(..., create=TRUE)`. The latter resets/loses a lot of optimization (in just about any DBMS), and can have connection complications with query resources potentially being held between `drop` and (re)create.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable inputs: Lastly I was droping the table, amd again update with new values using dbWriteTable(). So as you suggest it is not a good way to proceed with. I will delete records from mytable and write dbWriteTable(create=False) to update the table with new values.  The following code i will use:  dbSendUpdate(conn, "delete from mytable") ; dbWriteTable(conn,"mytable", mydataframe, create= FALSE,overwrite=TRUE); Is this correct??